# Cancel jQuery event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have setup onclick event handler in the following manner:

```
element.onclick = function() { /*code */ }
```

Imagine there are event handlers setup using jQuery method bind() or similar handlers.

```
$('element').bind('click', function(){/*another function*/})
```

How can I prevent invoking handler defined with jQuery from the handler I have described in the beginning?

NB stopPropagation() and etc. jQuery's methods doesn't work from that function, because it is passed with native event object.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but maybe this will help:

You can create a new event object (compliant with W3C DOM) via jQuery's exposed Event constructor:

For example:

```
element.onclick = function(e) {
    var aBetterEventObject = jQuery.Event(e);
    // Now you can do what you want: (Cross-browser)
    aBetterEventObject.preventDefault()
    aBetterEventObject.isDefaultPrevented()
    aBetterEventObject.stopPropagation()
    aBetterEventObject.isPropagationStopped()
    aBetterEventObject.stopImmediatePropagation()
    aBetterEventObject.isImmediatePropagationStopped()
}
```

---

EDIT: Reading through your question again, I don't think propagation is the problem - you seem to want to cancel an event handler from running within an event handler - I'm not sure this is possible. You could just unbind all handlers (*jQuery(elem).unbind('click')*) but I don't think that's what you're after...

Answer (score 5):

try to add the following line in the jQuery event handler:

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 5):

Following on from JimmyP's answer. I've tried this

```
$('#x').click( function(e){
    alert('hello');
});
document.getElementById('x').onclick = function(){
    $('#x').unbind('click');
    alert("goodbye");
}
```

The jQuery event runs once in this example. I don't think you can rely on the order of handlers being invoked however you define them, so I guess you'll have to accept that the jQuery event might fire once. Adding the onclick first does prevent the jQuery event from firing at all but, as I said, I don't think that's reliable.

Comment: 2meouw: As I have explained, unbind will discard handler alerting 'hello' forever. It is not good :) the use case can be: document.getElementById('x').onclick = function() { if ( /*some case*/ ) { /* prevent calling function alerting 'HELLO' */ } } So when I'll get another click on the element, the case could be false and handler should be invoked. Am I clear? :)

Comment: +1 I don't think that you can guarantee the order in which event handlers are called

Answer (score 2):

Jquery has a method for namespacing events. http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

You can add, trigger and remove separate functions bound to the same event via namespaces:

```
$("a").bind("click.custom1",function(){ ... });
$("a").bind("click.custom2",function(){ ... });
$("a").trigger("click.custom2");
$("a").unbind("click.custom2");
```

As long as you unbind the namespaced event your normal onclick should be unaffected. You may have to bind two separate namespaces to the click event as above if that doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can only change handler attached with inline method. I can't influence binding with jQuery - it can be done by another developer when he will reuse my code.

Comment: What's the setup then? Are you developing some javascript to add to an existing jquery script? Perhaps there's another element you could add your onclick to that bubble up through to the element with the jquery event attached.

Comment: I'm developing kind of plugin. Shortly, for some cases it should prevent any activities caused by event happened on the element. ex. it should prevent any event handlers triggering on certain events. Handlers can be attached by users - using jquery or inline techique.

Comment: [continue...]I can intefere only in inline handlers to add my stuff before, thus cancel that handler. After that jquery setup handlers will be invoked. I want to prevent this

Comment: I don't think that you can guarantee the order in which event handlers are called - it may well be that the jQuery handler has already executed once your event fires...

Comment: True, I can't guarantee. But as to my experience, onclick inline handler is always first :)

Comment: That doesn't mean it will ALWAYS fire first.