# jQuery - Bind click to all elements excluding class?

Tags: jquery, click

am trying to bind a click to all elements that don't have a specific class.

I tried the following and after some googleing, it looks like it the right thing to do.

```
$('*:not(.class)').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked...');
});

$(':not(.class)').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked...');
});
```

Now, what I've just realised while writing this is that elements are layered on top of other elements, and all the elements under a click trigger a click too? Is this correct? I think it is as when the following code is executed I would get between 3 and 6 "clicks" per click.

```
$('*').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

Does anyone have any light to shed?

**EDIT (Already):** Ive just thought of a workaround, as follows:

```
$('*').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('class')) {
        console.log('click');
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('click');
    }
});
```

**LOGIC:** This "class" element will be the top layered element and therefore will trigger the first click (theory-crafting) therefore is it has the class we return/break;

Comment: Try cancelling the event inside your handler:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/491707/440704

Comment: yup, it's called event propogation. event bubbling too.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've worked out what's going on and its working well now, thanks for your input.  Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). This will prevent all elements below the `clicked` item from firing as well.

```
$('*:not(.class)').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Clicked...');
});
```

Comment: I've put this into play and it works perfectly for its intended function. Although, its not a solution for my original problem its definitely worth knowing, thanks.